# In HQL, How to get comma separated string from subquery result in select clause?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have a requirement to display the sub-query result as comma separated string in HQL.

```
select DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       (select FIRST_NAME 
          FROM EMPLOYEES 
         where DEPARTMENT_ID =90) as Employee_Names 
 FROM DEPARTMENTS 
where DEPARTMENT_ID =90;
```

The sub-query result in the select clause i need to show as comma separated values.

Any help is appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Comment: Join two tables, group by `department_id` and use [listagg() within group()](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030) function to produce the desired result.

Comment: @Nicholas, thanks for reply. But i need do this in HQL. Not in sql. In SQL i have already tried its working. I cannot change my existing HQL quey to SQL as it has major impact.

Answer (score 3):

I see two possible solution.

**First**

Do it in Oracle:

```
select
  d.DEPARTMENT_ID,
  listagg(FIRST_NAME, ',') within group(order by FIRST_NAME) as Employee_Name
FROM
  DEPARTMENTS d join EMPLOYEES e
  on d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
where    
  d.DEPARTMENT_ID = 90
group by
  d.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

It has limitation : If total length of concateneted strings >4000 then code would fail.

**Second**

I assume this code is needed for some report then you can collect all FIRST_NAME and then manually read `ResultSet`(If you code works in Java) and combine data as you want. Then you can overhead limit of 4000 characters in Oracle.

```
 select
  d.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
  FIRST_NAME as Employee_Name
FROM
  DEPARTMENTS d join EMPLOYEES e
  on d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
where
  d.DEPARTMENT_ID =90
```